# Linux rsync command

Tags: linux, terminal, rsync

I work now with a Linux Server and an Apple Mac. Each morning I update my data on my MacBook with the command `rsync -a -v  server:~/work_dir ~/`. I looked up the manual already, but I can not found any command which helps me. Because I wanted the command to delete the files which are not any more on the server automatically. But when I delete a file on the server and run the `rsync` command, the files is still on my laptop. Do I use the wrong command? Or do I miss an option?

Comment: What did you find when you searched the rsync manual for "delete"?

Comment: Ah ok I looked again. It is behind the option -e. Do I have to use -e --delet or just --delet? I looked for a option on its own. Edit: Got it, got a sign to much. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your script is adapted to look like this,

```
MASTER="server:${HOME}/work_dir"
REPLICA="${HOME}/"

rsync --archive --delete --verbose "${MASTER}" "${REPLICA}"
```

the **--delete** option will delete any files existing in REPLICA that do not exist in MASTER.  I will assume you meant to have rsync create the directory "work_dir" in your laptop ${HOME} if it did not exist.  Otherwise, as a failsafe, I would create "work_dir" on the laptop and add the trailing "/" to the MASTER definition.

Note that there are many modes of behaviour for that delete action, controlling the timing of when the delete occurs.

I recommend against using

```
--delete-before
--delete-during
```

unless the REPLICA is a folder intended as a **handoff buffer for other downstream processes**.

If REPLICA is **intended to be a duplicate** of MASTER, then it is highly recommended that you use the delete o**ptions which preserve all data until after the copying** has been verified as good.  That leaves you with the two options

```
--delete-delay
--delete-after
```

of which the **--delete-delay** is likely the preferred choice because it won't force a second scan of the REPLICA to locate the files to be purged.